# Heroku application error after deployment of my MERN application

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, deployment

[complete error log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fJCF.png)
[coplete error log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuBGp.png)

2021-05-27T05:54:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-27T05:56:22.396351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2021-05-27T05:56:29.437265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=ec3f4b22-7e21-4c24-a679-d9f8ef1c7e23 fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T05:56:30.409830+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=8bb728b9-ef47-4a23-b06e-abe7334f82bb fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T05:57:32.200085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=8c67200b-e97a-4f11-9412-ff1f9a5c9f9b fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T05:57:33.051339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=49816455-335e-43c0-8510-8eac82fa6bf1 fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T06:00:59.708138+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=3d392317-ef11-4f22-89f2-e6bb12683f49 fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T06:01:00.750294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=b8c02355-9ca9-49e9-a8fe-e6648210dca7 fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T06:51:46.957912+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=8b4a33d2-7352-48a5-9d7f-c4c60313b24b fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T06:51:47.856224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-savannah-94452.herokuapp.com request_id=f5c69e61-2942-40c8-9be0-f368608ee4de fwd="43.247.159.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

---

I deployed my MERN application on heroku and when I open the deployed application it shows "Application Error". Used the command "heroku logs --tail" which was given by heroku to log the errors and the above error log was displayed and "MODULE NOT FOUND" was shown but I am not able to find that path or this is some other error. Please help me resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you hard coded any `port` in your js script?

Comment: no, I have used const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 while deploying.